# Most efficient way to strip a % from u'96.9%' and return a float

Tags: python, string, unicode, type-conversion

Let's say I run a BeautifulSoup strainer and get some unicode back like `u'96.9%'` and I want only the numeric values (and the decimal) to get printed out to a file.

It seems pretty straightforward to make a small function that would split the `str(u'96.9%')` at the % symbol and keep only the `[0]` first part (the 96.9), but is this the most efficient / fastest way?

```
float(str(c).split("%")[0])
Out[227]: 96.9
```

Comment: `float(u'96.9%'[:-1])` is faster

Comment: Faster, but Martin makes a good point, below.  But this is definitely "the answer" to the question I posed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the character from the end of the string:

```
float(c.rstrip(u'%'))
```

`float()` is fine with Unicode strings, no need to convert the value to a string first. When calling `str.rstrip()` on a `unicode` object, it is best to pass in a `unicode` object to specify what characters to remove.

You may want to strip whitespace too, especially when extracting this from a webpage:

```
float(c.rstrip(u'% \n\t\r\xa0'))
```

This'll remove any of the characters in the argument, until none are left on the right-hand-side of the string. This means any percent signs as well as arbitrary whitespace is removed from the end. `float()` can handle whitespace just fine, but if there is whitespace between the percent character and the end of the string you'd fail to remove the percent sign otherwise.

Demo:

```
>>> c = u'96.9%'
>>> float(c.rstrip(u'%'))
96.9
>>> float(c.rstrip(u'% \n\t\r\xa0'))
96.9
>>> c = u'96.9%  \n   '
>>> float(c.rstrip(u'%'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 96.9%      
>>> float(c.rstrip(u'% \n\t\r\xa0'))
96.9
```

Comment: This faster or comment above?

Comment: @Canuckish: using slicing would be faster, but then you have to be 100% certain that there is *always* going to be a percent symbol and it is *always* the last character. With HTML scraping, I'd always hedge on the side of *there will be extra whitespace* and use `.rstrip()` to remove the whitespace for me. That method is much more robust.

Comment: who cares about micorperformance - first priority is correctness, second robustness.

Comment: @Canuckish: and unless you are going to do this operation in a critical section, repeating this thousands and thousands of times, I'd not worry about the small performance differences between the two approaches, *anyway*.

Comment: Still the man, @MartijnPieters.  Good point, too, @ ch3ka. I think above comment may have been pointed at my OP of "efficiency." But I think you're right, especially in this case as there are two datapoints per page, and 3,007 (county) pages.